# How can I make legend next to my piechart in R?

Tags: r, charts, legend, pie-chart

I have made a piechart in R with the next code:

```
#make slices
slices <- c(19, 26, 55)

# Define some colors 
colors <- c("yellow2","olivedrab3","orangered3")

# Calculate the percentage for each day, rounded to one decimal place
slices_labels <- round(slices/sum(slices) * 100, 1)

# Concatenate a '%' char after each value
slices_labels <- paste(slices_labels, "%", sep="")

# Create a pie chart with defined heading and custom colors and labels
pie(slices, main="Sum", col=colors, labels=slices_labels, cex=0.8)

# Create a legend at the right   
legend("topright", c("DH","UT","AM"), cex=0.7, fill=colors)
```

But I want the legend next to my piechart. I have also tried the following code: `legend("centreright", c("DH","UT","AM"), cex=0.7, fill=colors)`.
But this does not give me a legend next to my pie chart.

Which code do I have to use to make a legend next to my pie chart in the middle?

Comment: `lengend` doesn't recognize `"centreright"`. See `?legend` for details. Does `legend("right", c("DH","UT","AM"), cex=0.7, fill=colors)` give the desired result?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already the answer;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can play with the `x` and `y` argument from `legend` (cf `?legend`):

```
legend(.9, .1, c("DH","UT","AM"), cex = 0.7, fill = colors)
```

However, a pie chart may not be the best way to represent your data, because our eye is not very good in assessing angles. The only usecase where a pie chart seems reasonable to me is when comparing 2 categories, because due to watches we can assess these proportions rather easily.

[image]

Comment: A +1 for pointing out that pie-charts are not the best way to visualize data :-) (which is also highlighted in the help page, see `?pie`)

Comment: Thanks for the code it works! I have to make piecharts to visualize the data.

Comment: I think it's good to set piecharts in a thesis so that other people can understand your data in one sight

Comment: Well that's my point, I think you _cannot_ understand a pie chart easily, as judging angles is not as easy as judging a position. I think that's also the reason why you labelled the slices with the percentages, because otherwise it will be difficult to judge the proportions. A quick google search gives you tons of material advocating against the use of pies (e.g. http://www.businessinsider.com/pie-charts-are-the-worst-2013-6?IR=T)